# Add a project into a workspace doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode5, xcode-workspace

I'm trying to add the [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC/tree/master/examples/BarcodeScanner) into my project but when I try to import a file in myViewController.h it doesn't allow it.

I click in my project and I choose "Add files to MyProject"

[image]

What do I have to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Read the "Getting Started" section on the [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC) website. Note step 2.

Comment: I've already done it... but still doesn't work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". BTW - you should not be trying to do what you are doing in your question.

Comment: I need to import a file of "ZXingObj". When I say that "it doesn't work", is because I can't import it. Xcode don't display the option to me.

Comment: As I said, you should not be doing that. No where in the instructions are you told to add the ZXingObjC project like you are trying to do. Read Step 2 of the instructions. It says to DRAG it into your project.

Comment: From the ZXingObjC site: "2. Drag the ZXingObjC *folder* onto Xcode." From the screenshot, you appear to be trying to add the project file to your project.

Comment: Thank's @davidf2281, you were right. I was dragging the project and not the whole folder. Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's necessary drag whole folder and not just the project how I was making.